# Alternate way to use 'INSERT tempTable EXEC storedProcedure' to get data

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a new stored procedure that contain of following script:

```
Insert into #tmpTable
Exec dbo.SP_GetData '2016-11-01'
```

and above script causes a SQL Server error message

> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

because there is another `INSERT EXEC` inside the `SP_GetData` stored procedure and according to a few hours of reading on this error message, I can't have two `INSERT EXEC` or I will get that error.

I found several alternatives such as using inline query to insert into temp table and modify the existing `SP_GetData` stored procedure but both way can't work for me. In my case, it's a must to depend on `SP_GetData` as it involve many complicated process and must not be changed.

I just need to retrieve all data from the `SP_GetData` in my new stored procedure and return.

Please let me know what is my alternatives on this.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but `SP_` prefix is just an example in this post. I'm not putting actual code here because actual code is very long and hard to understand

Comment: Erland Sommarskog wrote an extensive article explaining [How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(100),@Date VARCHAR(100) 
SELECT @Date = '2016-11-01' 
SELECT @Query = 'dbo.SP_GetData '''+@Date+'''' 
INSERT INTO #tmpTable 
EXEC (@Query)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the same error occur at my side. The above answer is still using 'INSERT EXEC' to run the stored procedure so generally, it will fall back to the same problem.